# Stop Primary Slide Animation only for secondary

Tags: javascript, css

I have managed to get the look and feel I want for my nav, my issue is when I don't want the nav to slide up on the first state when you refresh you can see the first nav slide real quick I want it to go up with the site then the nav with a background slides in then slide back up on scroll but the nav that has no background I don't want to slide at all.

[Example](http://www.blacksquad.com/bsq-news/)

```js
(function($) {
  var header = $('.siteHeader');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      header.addClass('fixed active').off('transitionend');  
    } else if (header.hasClass('active')) {
      header.removeClass('active').one('transitionend', function() {
        header.removeClass('fixed');
    header.addClass('active');
      });
    }
  }).scroll();

})(jQuery);

$(window).resize(function() {   
    $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
 $('.siteHeader').removeClass('fixed');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);   
    $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.headerNav {
 height: auto; 
 float: right;
 margin: 0px;
}
.headerNav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.siteHeader {
 height: 86px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 11;
 background-color: red;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
 transition: transform .3s;
 -moz-transform: translateY(-86px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-86px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-86px);
 transform: translateY(-86px);
}

.siteHeader.fixed {
 width: 100%;
 height: 66px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: #000;
 -moz-transform: translateY(-130px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-130px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-130px);
 transform: translateY(-130px);
 transition: transform .3s;
}

.siteHeader.active {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
 transform: translateY(0px);
 transition: transform .3s;
}

.siteHeader.fixed.active {
 -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
 transform: translateY(0px);
 transition: transform .3s;
}

.main{
background-color: grey;
height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="siteHeader">
    <nav class="headerNav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
   </ul>   
  </nav>  
 </div>
  
  <div class="main">Content</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the initial nav sliding in, either on refresh or scroll.

Comment: @Bricky if you scroll down then scroll up when it returns to the transparent nav it slide down does the same on refresh

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. What browser are you using?
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/xT9IgHyrFYR1I9nBT2

Comment: @Bricky I have tried in chrome, firefox , explorer, opera and phone it all does the same now I changed the background color to red when you scroll back to the top of the page you will see the red div slide back down

Comment: @Bricky I think you mis understood I want my nav to function like the example but my code shows the red div sliding back up and out

Comment: @Codi I hope my answer helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a start... 
Looking at your example website's source code, there are 2 elements, both containing the "header". I replicated that idea in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chroline_/vvwrkb2e/1/).

```js
(function($) {
  var header = $('.siteHeader');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("body").scrollTop() > 86) {
      header.addClass('fixed active').off('transitionend');
    } else if (header.hasClass('active')) {
      header.removeClass('active').one('transitionend', function() {
        header.removeClass('fixed');
        header.addClass('active');
      });
    }
  }).scroll();

})(jQuery);

$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
  $('.siteHeader').removeClass('fixed');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).scrollTop(0);
  $('.siteHeader').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.headerNav {
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
}

.headerNav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.siteHeader,
.siteHeaderNoFloat {
  height: 86px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.siteHeader {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-86px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-86px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-86px);
  transform: translateY(-86px);
}

.siteHeader.fixed {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-130px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-130px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-130px);
  transform: translateY(-130px);
  transition: transform .3s;
}


/*.siteHeader.active {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: transform .3s;
}*/

.siteHeader.fixed.active {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.main {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 1500px;
  padding-top: 86px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="siteHeaderNoFloat">
  <nav class="headerNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="siteHeader">
  <nav class="headerNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="main">
  Content
</div>
```

When the .scrollTop of the body reaches 86px, the height of the header, the black fixed header shows up.
Hopefully this helps. Good luck!